# C# - Assign ConsoleKey then reassign using ConsoleKeyInfo

Tags: c#

What I'm trying to accomplish is have a `ConsoleKey` assigned to a variable then using `ConsoleKeyInfo` to modify the variable.

I'm getting errors saying `Cannot convert source type 'System.ConsoleKey' to target type 'System.ConsoleKeyInfo'`.

The reasoning behind this is I wish to have the user be able to reprogram the keys used inside the application.

I have this so far;

```
public static ConsoleKeyInfo keyboardkeynorth;
keyboardkeynorth = Console.ReadKey();
```

This works, but it doesn't allow me to start the program with `keyboardkeynorth` already set to `ConsoleKey.W`.

Elsewhere in the program I would call `keyboardkeynorth` to be used as a `ConsoleKey`

This may be simple but it seems to be eluding me.

Comment: I take it this is not possible from within the application?
I'm looking for what most applications can do by altering key bindings. I have not found anything that is possible via a console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realizing this is a short 3+ years after you asked...

```
public static ConsoleKeyInfo keyboardkeynorth = 
    new ConsoleKeyInfo('W', ConsoleKey.W, false, false, false);
```

And don't you want "north" to be 'N' initially? ;^)

It's a strange, verbose constructor, but does what you appear to be asking.

Comment: Works great! Thank you!
Better late than never.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete, and simple, program to show you how you might do this. I say simple because it doesn't take into consideration CTRL, ALT, or SHIFT -- and based on how I gather the custom key info you wouldn't even be able to set those because I'm using `ReadKey`. But you'll get the idea.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication23
{
    class Program
    {
        private static ConsoleKeyInfo keyAction1, keyAction2, keyAction3;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            InitializeKeyActions();

            Console.Write("Do you want a new key action for #1? ");
            var result = Console.ReadKey();
            if (result.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter) { UpdateKeyInfo("keyAction1", result); }
        }

        private static void UpdateKeyInfo(string keyName, ConsoleKeyInfo result)
        {
            var propertyInfo = typeof(Program).GetField(keyName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
            if (propertyInfo == null) { return; }

            var key = result.KeyChar;
            propertyInfo.SetValue(null, new ConsoleKeyInfo(key, (ConsoleKey)key, false, false, false));

            StringBuilder keyActions = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines("keyactions.ini"))
            {
                var kvp = line.Split(new char[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                if (kvp[0] != keyName)
                {
                    keyActions.AppendLine(line);
                    continue;
                }

                keyActions.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", kvp[0], result.KeyChar));
            }

            File.WriteAllText("keyactions.ini", keyActions.ToString());
        }

        private static void InitializeKeyActions()
        {
            if (!File.Exists("keyactions.ini"))
            {
                StringBuilder keyActions = new StringBuilder();
                keyActions.AppendLine("keyAction1: A");
                keyActions.AppendLine("keyAction2: B");
                keyActions.AppendLine("keyAction3: C");

                File.WriteAllText("keyactions.ini", keyActions.ToString());
            }

            foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines("keyactions.ini"))
            {
                var kvp = line.Split(new char[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                var propertyInfo = typeof(Program).GetField(kvp[0], BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
                if (propertyInfo == null) { continue; }

                var key = kvp[1].Trim()[0];
                propertyInfo.SetValue(null, new ConsoleKeyInfo(key, (ConsoleKey)key, false, false, false));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Michael. This seems a tad complicated for what I wish to accomplish. I also would like, if possible, to have the conversion done inside the application as opposed to creating an external file.